# document.evaluate with XPath only working if I inspect element first

Tags: javascript, iframe, ui-automation, console.log

All new to JavaScript and experiencing a frustrating problem.

So basically I'm trying to achieve a click as part of an automation process. Here's what I'm doing:

```
document.evaluate('//a[@aria-label="Salgsfakturaer" and @role="menuitem"]',document.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.click()
```

This works great from the console but ONLY if I've gone to the trouble of inspecting the element first! If I reload the page and fire off the same I get an error. Again I can then go and inspect the element and try again - and it works!

So what I'm thinking, and I'm no JavaScript expert, is that it has something to do with the main content being in an iframe and that the source is not loaded initially (only when I go to inspect). If this is a correct assumption, how can I handle this?

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Likely the page has not loaded the content you are looking for until later (ajax).

Comment: I have the same problem and really would like to know how to solve it... And I would not know how to produce a minimal reproducible example in this case.